# Grails prevent duplicate inserts

Tags: grails, groovy, grails-orm

how do i prevent duplicate inserts of a domain class?

```
Locations location = Locations.findByLocationXY(locationxy)
       if (location == null)
        {

            LocationManagement lm = new LocationManagement()
            location = lm.getSingaporeLocation(locationxy)
            location.save(flush:true)
        }

class Locations {

int id
String locationName
String locationXY

static constraints = {
    id(blank:false, unique:true)
    locationName (blank:false)
    locationXY (blank:false, unique:true)
}
def afterInsert = {

id= this.id
locationName = this.locationName
locationXY = this.locationXY
}
```

Comment: in your business model, what makes a location unique ? localtionXY ? locationName ? you should simply be able to put the unique constraint on that property - you dont have to check for the id

Comment: Yes there's constrain applied.. can I have a before insert and check?

Answer (score 4):

You have to let Grails handle this - no need for extra code if you define your contraints in the right way.

And as I can see, you already have a

```
locationXY (blank:false, unique:true)
```

So from what I read from the code, it should not be possible to insert another location with the same locationXY.

Have you checked the content of your database after running your code? Do you really get two lines in your table with the same `locationXY`?

btw: your line

```
location.save(flush:true)
```

will not throw an exception since you did not specify `failOnError:true`. So the following line might result in what you are expecting:

```
location.save(flush:true, failOnError:true)
```

PS: what is your `afterInsert` code for? I would jsut remove it for clarity.

Answer (score 0):

You dont need to add the constraints for id. This is done by grails automatically.
I think if you remove this, the program should execute as you expect. The only unique value then is locationXY.

Comment: I'm asking how to prevent same locationxy from insert!!

Comment: And thats the answer. If the only unique key is locationXY then grails (database) will not allow inserting the same locationXY twice...But you set twoe unique keys (btw. the wrong way) one on the id. Which is autogenerated for every entry. Thats the same as to have no unique key

Comment: Ok to make it a bit clearer. Delete the line `id(blank:false, unique:true)` and check for an exception that is thrown if you want to insert the equally `locationXY`.